# Multiple Selectors with jQuery .on()

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I have looked at the [.on() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for help with my particular use-case but I couldn't find the information on how to do it or if it can even be done.

I would like to attach a function to an event (say click) for two different "selectors", like this:

- one: `'div[id^="action_"]'`
- second: `'div[id^="user_"]'`

I have tried all the below combinations based on how jQuery normally handles multiples of things but some just don't work and the others will only process the first selector and ignore the second altogether:

```
// correct
$(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"], div[id^="user_"]' , function(){

// incorrect
$(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"] div[id^="user_"]' , function(){
$(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"]' || 'div[id^="user_"]' , function(){
$(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"]', 'div[id^="user_"]' , function(){
```

The first was what I was sure would work and when it didn't, led me to try everything else as clearly a shot in the dark attempt. Of the ones now marked incorrect, first one simply doesn't do anything, second and third one both result in the first being handled but not the second. The last one I was pretty sure doesn't work and I didn't expect it to, since it holds the `[,data]` portion of the syntax but for sake of completeness, tried it.

- Am I simply overlooking something as simple as syntax here?
- Or, can this simply not be done as-is?
- **Now clear that it works but something else might be interfering!**

any help on this would be greatly appreciated before I just go ahead and split them into two pieces of code which would be ugly and messy. TIA.

### Resolution

Thanks to Frank's answer and kind fiddles, it was confirmed that my initial instinct as shown on line one of the tried methods was correct (*I have updated it to show more clearly what is correct and not*). I am still not certain why it didn't work as expected which led me to post the question but I suspect that the problem probably arose from GM and/or possible interference from something on the page itself, and not the code. If I find out the exact source of the observation, I will edit this to reflect it for sake of completeness.

Comment: If you have control over the HTML, it would be a good idea to create a new class such as `user-action` and apply it to the desired elements. Also you should consider attaching the listener to a more appropriate DOM element. So say that these actions were contained in a section with class of `user-container`, then your jQuery could be `$('.user-container').on('click', '.user-action', function(event) { });` which would make your code more versatile and readable.

Comment: @NicholasByfleet thank you and I agree, would do that if I could but unfortunately in this instance, I do not have access to the HTML :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you mentioned---that is, `$(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"], div[id^="user_"]', ...)`---is definitely correct, and working based on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg1pmd0o/)

Also as alternative, you could name your function and simply pass the function name to `on()`, so you can re-use the named function:

```
function myCallBack(event) {
   alert($(event.target).html());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click", 'div[id^="action_"], div[id^="user_"]', myCallBack);
})
```

See this approach work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sg1pmd0o/2/).

Also, be aware of [event performance with `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance), particularly when (1) attaching  delegated events to `document`, and (2) when using more complex selectors. One thing to note about #1 is this

> attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document

Comment: Interesting for me it only processed the first selector, not the second - strange indeed. Thank you for the fiddles, they do indeed work and I appreciate your efforts. For the life of me, I don't know why but just now I tried it again and sure as hell it worked, I am so flabbergasted as to what the heck didn't process yesterday that is working today. Regardless, to my great embarrassment, thank you for your assistance. Final thought, yes, I am aware of the performance issues with this but since it won't be heavy, it should be manageable. Thank you again so very much.

Comment: I have no idea my friend, except that this site is full of malicious and hateful trolls with nothing to contribute; who cowardly go around doing things like with the blessing of the admins who effectively hide their identities by design and condone it by inaction and lack of accountability. If the users who did this had their names attached to it, I bet you it would stop real quick. They expose people's personal bookmarks but when they do things like this, their identity should be hidden; its a systematic failure.