# on method with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that multiple selectors are allowed and I've seen [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178769/multiple-selectors-with-jquery-on)

I tried to [replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/3f2nw1sj/), but it is not working as expected:

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("#tbl").on("dblclick", 'td:not(:first-child), td:not(:last-child)', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

It works if I use only first-child or last-child, but not together. I'd like only cells that are not first and last in a row to be clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you select the `<table>` and then try to filter out `<td>` which are children of the `<table>`. That can't work as you can only filter out things from the base selector.
You should select the `<td>` direclty and then filter out first and last child from them.

```js
$("#tbl td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)").on("dblclick", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked, but in the example I saw the structure was .on( event, selector1, selector2, function) Should I ask another question or could you tell me the difference here?

Comment: This would be another question but in short: your base selector has the targets the `table` from which you cannot subtract the `td`s